# woocommerce Checkout fields are gone in safari

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, safari

Checkout works fine in windows, it show you 2 tabs in left sidebar, Client information and payment information, but, in safari, the sidebar is gone, and only show the payment view.

Chrome 
[image]

Safari
[image]

Do you have some idea how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have the multi-step checkout plugin, disable it. it has become incompatible with the newer safari versions. hth